# SHOW PARTITIONS with order by in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I have this query:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS tablename;
```

Result is:

```
dt=2018-01-12
dt=2018-01-20
dt=2018-05-21
dt=2018-04-07
dt=2018-01-03
```

This gives the list of partitions per table. The partition field for this table is `dt` which is a date column.  I want to see the partitions ordered.

The documentation doesn't explain how to do it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-partitions.html

I tried to add order by:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS tablename order by dt;
```

But it gives:

> AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException;

Answer (score 11):

AWS currently (as of [Nov 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/amazon-athena-announces-availability-of-engine-version-2/)) supports two versions of the Athena engines.  How one selects and orders partitions depends upon which version is used.

Version 1:

Use the `information_schema` table.  Assuming you have `year`, `month` as partitions (with one partition key, this is of course simpler):

```sql
WITH 
 a as (
SELECT partition_number as pn, partition_key as key, partition_value as val
FROM   information_schema.__internal_partitions__
WHERE  table_schema = 'my_database'
       AND table_name = 'my_table'
 )
SELECT 
  year, month
FROM (
    SELECT val as year, pn FROM a WHERE key = 'year'
) y
JOIN (
    SELECT val as month, pn FROM a WHERE key = 'month'
) m ON m.pn = y.pn
ORDER BY year, month
```

which outputs:

```
  year month
0 2018    10
0 2018    11
0 2018    12
0 2019    01
...
```

Version 2:

Use the built-in `$partitions` functionality, where the partitions are explicitly available as columns and the syntax is much simpler:

```sql
SELECT year, month FROM my_database."my_table$partitions" ORDER BY year, month
```

```
  year month
0 2018    10
0 2018    11
0 2018    12
0 2019    01
...
```

For more information, see:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html#querying-glue-catalog-listing-partitions

Comment: `SELECT year, month FROM my_database."my_table$partitions" ORDER BY year, month` is brillant +1

Answer (score 2):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735925/show-partitions-with-order-by-in-amazon-athena#comment88484699_50737893) it sounds like you're looking to sort the partitions as a way to figure out whether or not a specific partition exists. For this purpose I suggest you use the Glue API instead of querying Athena. Run `aws glue get-partition help` or check your preferred SDK's documentation for how it works.

There is also a variant to list all partitions of a table, run `aws glue get-partitions help` to read more about that. I don't think it returns the partitions in alphabetical order, but it has operators for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The `SHOW PARTITIONS` command will not allow you to order the result, since this command does not produce a resultset to sort. This command only produces a string output.

You can on the other hand query the partition column and then order the result by value.

```
select distinct dt from tablename order by dt asc;
```

Comment: My goal is to check if the partition was created. Your query will show me data from the table regardless to which partition the data is related.

Comment: This solution will scan through all data in the table, which might be slow and very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM database_name."table_name$partitions" ORDER BY column_name
```

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-partitions.html